# After adding trunk, branches and tags directories to established svn, i can still not create tags

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657337/how-to-add-tags-trunk-branches-to-established-svn-repo), I moved my trunk "up one level" when the need for branching and tagging occured.

my layout was:

```
 /
   /src
   /inc
   /doc
```

and now is

/
   /trunk
      /src
      /inc
      /doc
   /tags

/branches

However, i seem to be unable to create a tag or branch from a revision before the move.
When I command the branch, TortoiseSVN gives this error: "access to '/usvn/svn/MyAppName/!svn/bc/1187' forbidden". However, i have read-and-write permission and the case of my path is OK too.

Is there a method short of export-from-trunk-and-reimport-to-tags to avoid this error?

Comment: What command are you using to branch or tag?

Comment: If you use path-based authorisation, you have to check it. And try `svn log ROOT-URL` from console, show results

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6470530/282194)  One possibility that jumps out at me (and which I've personally experienced) is that you may have the path correctly cased, but the server portion of the URL might have a different case.